# BOOL becomes false after archiving array

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I am trying to debug this app but there is one big problem. When I try to save my array to a data file everything is working. However if I close the app and reopen a boolean in the array becomes nil. Here is the code to save the array:

```
NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.alist toFile:filePath];
NSLog(@"%@", self.alist.description);

- (NSString*)dataFilePath
{
    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AssignmentInfo.data"];
    NSFileHandle *file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];

    if (!file) {
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil]) {
        }
        else
            file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];

    }

    return filePath;
}
```

Inside the array is a custom class I created... Here is the code for the class:

```
-(NSString *)description
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    NSString *dateTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: self.dateTime];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Class: %@\r Assignment Title: %@ \rAssignment Description: %@ \rDue: %@ \r%s", self.className, self.assignmentTitle, self.assignmentDescription, dateTimeString,self.notifcationStatus ? "Notification On" : "Notification Off"];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];

    self.className = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"className"];
    self.assignmentTitle = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"assignmentTitle"];
    self.assignmentDescription = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"assignmentDescription"];
    self.dateTime = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"dateTime"];
    self.notifcationStatus = [aDecoder decodeBoolForKey:@"notifcationStatus"];

    return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.className forKey:@"className"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.assignmentTitle forKey:@"assignmentTitle"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.assignmentDescription forKey:@"assignmentDescription"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.dateTime forKey:@"dateTime"];
    [aCoder encodeBool:self.notifcationStatus forKey:@"notificationStatus"];
}
```

`self.notifcationStatus` is the array that becomes `FALSE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps using the same key, when archiving and unarchiving:

```
self.notifcationStatus = [aDecoder decodeBoolForKey:@"notifcationStatus"];

...

[aCoder encodeBool:self.notifcationStatus forKey:@"notificationStatus"];
```

you're using two different keys: `notifcationStatus` when decoding, and `notificationStatus` when encoding. (There's a missing **i**).

In this situation, it would be better to use a #define macro or equivalent to ensure that the same key is used in both places (hat tip: @godel9):

```
// somewhere in your .h, for instance:
#define kNotificationStatus @"notificationStatus"


self.notifcationStatus = [aDecoder decodeBoolForKey: kNotificationStatus];

...

[aCoder encodeBool:self.notifcationStatus forKey: kNotificationStatus];
```

Comment: You might want to point out that it would be better to use a #define macro or equivalent to ensure that the same key is used in both places.